# Como recarregar a página no Express / nodejs

Tags: node.js, express.js

Criei um projeto novo com Express e Nodejs, onde defini uma rota "/status". Cada vez que essa rota for acessada, deverá executar uma rotina no script `/routes/status.js`. Exemplo: Se eu executar um F5 no navegador com o endereço `http://192.168.137.2:3000/status`, teria que executar o `/routes/status.js`, mas isso não ocorre.

Imagino que esse seja comportamento é o natural do Express. Porém, como faço para conseguir que seja executado dessa forma que descrevi ou então de outra forma qualquer?

Answer (score 1):

Você esta usando algum módulo para carregar sua rota, senão eu indico um chamado consign. Voce ira instalar via npm

```
npm install --save consign
```

Importara no sua aplicaçao

```
var consign = require('consign');
```

Definira onde estará as rotas

```
consign()
.include('app/routes')
.into(app)
```

E irá criar normalmente seu aruivo status.js recebendo

```
module.exports = function(app){
app.post('/status', function(req, res){
    //aqui vc direciona para sua view       
})
```

}

Comment: Não uso o "consign", mas pelo que entendi na documentação é algo como o "nodemon" que já estou usando para a mesma função. Mas não é disso que trata o problema em questão. Eu estou falando de uma rota que o usuário está abrindo no browser, ou seja, um endereço comum. Ao carregar a página, o script referente a aquela rota será executado. Mas não estou vendo isso acontecer quando carrego a página.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem o problema, ou você não declarou a rota, ou a rota esta chamando o arquivo incorretamente.

index.js

```
const app = express()
const status = require('./routes/status.js')

app.get('/status', status)
```

status.js

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    ... code ...
}
```